# Unit Test Function which Contains Promises

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, promise, chai, sinon

I have this function:

```
function _init()
{ 
    return _getNetDesc() // this is a promise
    .then(data => {

       // do something
    })  
    .then(() => {

        return _getNetOperation(); // this is a promise
    })
    .then( () =>{
        return _getNetNodeList(); // this is a promise
    }) 

    .catch( e =>
    {
        logger.error("JZW","init",e);

    });
}
```

In order to test if this function throws, I wrote in `mocha/sinon/chai`:

```
it("should throw eception for no GW", async () => {
        _getNetDesc = sinon.stub().throws();
        const test = await jzw.init;
        expect(test).to.be.rejected;

    });
```

But I get

```
 TypeError: [Function: _init] is not a thenable.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing to call the function and reject the promise:

```
it("should throw eception for no GW", async () => {
  _getNetDesc = sinon.stub().returns(Promise.reject(...)); // returns a rejected promise
  const test = await jzw.init(); // call the function to get the promise
  expect(test).to.be.rejected;
});
```